# Significance of "prepost" in the word Preposterous?

Tags: linguistics

What does the chunk "prepost" mean in the context of the word preposterous?

Comment: As Brits say - 'arse about face'

Comment: Split it after 'pre' - _prae_ (Latin, 'coming before'), _posterus_ (Latin, 'coming after') -> _praeposterus_ (Latin 'absurd', i.e. back-to-front, reversed) . Anglicised to preposterous (16th century).

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense to me now. Quite an inventive phrase.